# Nativescript / Angular CA from user not loading in devices, only in emulators

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

This is my `network_security_config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

This is the error:

> "error": { JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Failed to connect to /192.168.1.67:5000\n    at new ZoneAwareError
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:91976:33)\n
>   at onRequestComplete
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:98865:34)\n
>   at Object.onComplete (file:
>   node_modules@nativescript\core\http\http-request\http-request.android.js:43:0)"
>   JS:   } JS: }

I use `tns run android` to work with all devices and emulators.

And I have a own CA . Works well in emulators but not in physical devices. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Your physical device and emulator running same Android version? Whats the version?

Comment: Yes. Android 9.

Comment: Where is `user` directory located?

Comment: Is the storage in android for my CA. I need to install in my devices to make work my app.

Comment: Please share the exact path to user from your project root folder.

Comment: I solved. Was a firewall problem.